# Compare last pull file and the modified file in Git

Tags: git

How to compare last pull file and the modified file in Git? 
I mean is there any way to see what changes I have done to a file before commit?

Comment: Can you please clarify what it is that you're trying to do? It's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to view the changes you have done to a file before adding and committing. For viewing the modified changes you could do a:

```
git diff -- your/file/path
```